# Getters from vuex story doesn't show data

Tags: vue.js, vuex, store

I have database in MongoDB

```
user:{
     matchesList:[{
     kdList:String,
     winsMatchesList:String
     }]
```

I've created Vuex.Store and I have some getters

```
      matchesList:  state => state.matchesList,

        matchesListKD:  state => {
            let matchesList = []
            for (let g of state.matchesList) matchesList.push(g.kdList)
            return matchesList
        }
```

Then in component where I want to use it these code works property

```
apollo:{
    kd: {
    query: GETMATCHESLIST,
      update(data){
        console.log("data", this.$store.getters.user.matchesList)

      }}
  }
```

but below code shows undefined

```
apollo:{
    kd: {
    query: GETMATCHESLIST,
      update(data){
        console.log("data", this.$store.getters.user.matchesListKD)

      }}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here:

```
matchesList:  state => state.matchesList,

matchesListKD:  state => {
    let matchesList = []
    for (let g of state.matchesList) matchesList.push(g.kdList)
    return matchesList
}
```

You are using `state.matchesList` as the state, but `matchesList` is `getters`, not a `state`.

If you want to use `state.matchesList` as a `state` then move it to the `state` object, but then you can't use it as `this.$store.getters.user.matchesList` .